# The linq query in Entity Framework is too slow

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I am using EF6 (model-first) that connects to Oracle 11G.

I have 3 tables A,B,C, and I defined the right FK to get the relationships:

```
1. B is a child of A.
2. C is a child of B.
```

Now, I'm running the following code (using eager loading) to get A with B and C:

```
var myQuery = from r in MyContext.A
                                 .Include(x => x.B.Select(y => y.C))
                                 .Where(a => a.sku == 2);
var res = myQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

As you can see I use include and select to eagerly retrieve A with its B's and the B with its C's.

My problem is that it takes around 4 seconds to run the `FirstOrDefault()` method.

I have tested it on TOAD, and the generated SQL executed in less than one second.

The retrieved object (i.e. populated A), is not so big (A has 5 B's and each B has 2 C's, and each table has ~10 columns).

Is there a way to improve the performance?

Comment: How many records do your tables have?

Comment: is this the first query that your application executes? the first query in EF always takes some time. Try to execute the the statement a second time. This should be much quicker.

Comment: A has ~100 records.
B has ~3000 records.
C has ~1000 records.
The result is about 20 records (from all 3 tables).
And this is not the first execution (I also tried to run it twice and still got bad performance)

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case `.Include( a => a.B.Select( y => y.C ) )` will execute another separate `SELECT` for every row in your result-set, which is suboptimal, instead you should (generally) `SELECT` from the most descendant table first, then use `Include` to `INNER JOIN` any parent data that you need.

Try this query instead:

```
 var query = context.C
    .Include( c => c.B )
    .Include( c => c.B.A )
    .Where( c => c.B.A.sku == 2 );
return query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, check your indexes.

Comment: `Include(x => x.B.Select(y => y.C))` is just the EF6 typed way to describe include path like `Include("B.C")`. While what you are suggesting is not a valid syntax.

Comment: @IvanStoev I use `Include( first => first.Second.Third )` fine in my own projects. I'm using EF6 with `DbExtensions` in scope.

Comment: Make sure `Second` is collection type, i.e. first (one) -> second (many) -> third (one). In OP sample, if `x.B` is single object, then `Select` would not compile.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ah, I misread OP's question. Still, isn't it better to go from child-to-parent than in parent-to-child order?

Comment: Frankly the OP query is just fine and is basically the correct and pretty standard way of eager loading such model. I have no idea why he has performance issues,

Comment: I dont think that it is an indexes issue, cause I get good performance when running the SQL on TOAD

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, to solve the slowness issue, I selected only the columns that I was interested in, and put it into a DTO.

```
var myQuery = from r in MyContext.A
                             .Include(x => x.B.Select(y => y.C))
                             .Where(a => a.sku == 2)
                              Select new MyDTO
                              {
                                 ...
                              }
var res = myQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Also check out the .AsNoTracking() - it might speed things up slightly.  AsNoTracking may speed it up if list does not require change detection, but conversely if you are repeatedly querying for the same entities on the same context, you might actually see a performance benefit from enabling change tracking.